# Object orientated Javascript creating malformed data in embedded array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am using this code it works but I end up with data which looks like `["\"colour"\", "\"colour"\", "\"colour"\"]` inside my `"colours_available":[]` array in the example object below.

```
// Array holding object data
var arr = [];

// Example of object in array
{
  "id": 101,
  "name": "Scott",
  "colours_available: ["red", "blue", "black"],
  "key_group": 1
}

// Target id to check
var x = 101;

// Current colour in loop 
var colour = "silver";

// Get index of target (Search array for matching object)
objIndex = arr.findIndex((obj => obj.id == x));

// Check if data exists (A)
var z = arr[objIndex].colours_available.includes('"' + colour + '"');

// If data does not exist insert data (B)
if (z == false) {
    arr[objIndex].colours_available.push('"' + colour + '"');
}
```

I initially tried to post this data into the object array without wrapping and concatenating in quotation marks in (A) and (B) but that just created many arrays in my `"colours_available":[]` which looked like `["colour"],["colour"],["colour"]` in my example above.

How can I make my data import look more like `["colour","colour","colour"]` it is perplexing me as it works in examples on jsfiddle with strings but not with my data which is just xml data converted to JSON and why does it create new arrays when I remove quotation marks from (A) and (B) ?

Comment: I disagree this code is object oriented.

Comment: Please re-read [MCVE] guidance on posting code. It does not look like code in the post shows problem you have at all. Adding quotes to strings is very strange - it is very likely that your actual problem comes from `colour` not being string at all - but that's impossible to confirm based on the code posted. Please [edit] post to clarify.

Comment: With the code you provided (plus some syntax fixes) I get `colours_available: (4) ["red", "blue", "black", ""silver""]`. Take out the places you have `'"'` and the output is `colours_available: (4) ["red", "blue", "black", "silver"]`. I'm not able to recreate the output you reported. Can we see some of your actual input data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you end up with nested arrays if you remove the quotes, I suspect `colour` is actually an array and not a string. I suggest that you `console.log(colour)` inside the loop.

Reproductions:

```js
const colour = ['Silver']
let colours = []

// No quotes
colours.push(colour)
console.log(colours) // -> [["Silver"]]

// With quotes
colours = []
colours.push('"' + colour + '"')
console.log(colours) // -> ["\"Silver\""]

// Correct (assuming colour is an array with one item):
colours = []
colours.push(colour[0])
console.log(colours) // -> ["Silver"]

// Calling Array.prototype.toString() explicitly:
console.log(colour.toString()) // -> "Silver"

// Concatenated with other text:
console.log("The colour is: " + colour) // -> "The colour is Silver"

// Straight up console.logging the array:
console.log(colour) // -> ["Silver"]
```

The reason `'"' + ["Silver"] + '"'` becomes `"\"Silver\""` is that when you concatenate a string with an array, the array is silently converted to a string via the `Array.prototype.toString()` method. `["Silver"].toString()` returns `"Silver"`, for instance.

Comment: I tried this initially which just creates duplicate arrays e.g. `"colours_available: ["red"],["red"],["red"]` this part of the code is in a loop scanning and checking for data before import any ideas why it could be behaving like this?

Comment: See my edit - I think `colour` is an array, rather than a string. I will add a snippet to show that this would lead to the behaviour you're describing.

Comment: I'm working in node i logged it, I don't see an array `console.log("colour is equal to:" + colour);` output `colour is equal to: Green`

Comment: That's the wrong way to `console.log` it. You're doing the same thing that you're doing in the code where you concatenate the quotation marks around it. Just do `console.log(colour)` or `console.log('output colour', colour)`, and you'll see it's an array. Here you've concatenated a string with `colour`. If `colour` is an array, concatenating a string with it will cause its `toString()` method to be called, converting it into a string (see my working snippet for confirmation).

Comment: you were right tex it was array data, thanks for your help

Comment: No worries! Silent type coercion is one of Javascript's "features" that I'm not a big fan of, and try very hard to avoid / not depend on :)

Answer (score 0):

This code returns ["colour","colour","colour"] but I wasn't able to reproduce the `["\"colour"\", "\"colour"\", "\"colour"\"]` issue so it may be something in the actual input data.

```js
// Array holding object data
var arr = [];

// Example of object in array
var myObj={
  "id": 101,
  "name": "Scott",
  "colours_available": ["red", "blue", "black"],
  "key_group": 1
}

arr.push(myObj);
// Target id to check
var x = 101;

// Current colour in loop 
var colour = "silver";

// Get index of target (Search array for matching object)
objIndex = arr.findIndex((obj => obj.id == x));

// Check if data exists (A)
var z = arr[objIndex].colours_available.includes(colour);

// If data does not exist insert data (B)
if (z == false) {
    arr[objIndex].colours_available.push(colour);
}
console.log(arr)
```